# Current index of a letter in OnKeyDown

Tags: c#, richedit, richedit-control

I am trying to get the current index of the letter that typed in during OnKeyDown event.

For example, if I have a text in RichEdit Control as "MOVS,21"

I would like know the index of "(" when I change the string to "MOV(S,21" in the event "OnKeyDown".

Is there any way I can get this index? Appreciate your help.

regards,
Balan Sinniah

Comment: what do you mean by index? the current position of the inserted char or the pressed key index?

Comment: the current position of the inserted char

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general behavior of a richedit when it receives a KeyDown event, is to insert the corresponding char in the current carret position.

You should be able to get this position using the selectionStart and selectionEnd properties of the richedit.

```
private void richTextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(richTextBox1.SelectionStart.ToString());
    }
```

There are some edge cases that you will need to handle, for example, when the pressed key is a delete.